# use RxSwift's retryWhen operator to prompt the user for a retry or cancel

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am trying to make an iOS app using `MVVM` architecture. Now what I want is that if an observable fails, I will show the user a prompt asking if he wants to cancel or retry. This should be simple enough with `retryWhen` but retry is never called. Here my code:

```
.retryWhen({ (errorObservable: Observable<Error>) -> Observable<Error> in
  return promptFor("test", cancelAction: RetryResult.cancel, actions: [RetryResult.retry])
    .flatMap { action -> Observable<Error> in
      switch action {
      case .retry:
        return errorObservable
      case .cancel:
        return errorObservable.flatMap { Observable.error($0) }
      }
    }
})
```

prompt is just a method I took from RxSwiftExample and can be found in the repo, but for ease here it is:

```
func promptFor<Action : CustomStringConvertible>(_ message: String, cancelAction: Action, actions: [Action]) -> Observable<Action> {
#if os(iOS)
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "RxExample", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelAction.description, style: .cancel) { _ in
            observer.on(.next(cancelAction))
        })

        for action in actions {
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action.description, style: .default) { _ in
                observer.on(.next(action))
            })
        }

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController?.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return Disposables.create {
            alertView.dismiss(animated:false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
#elseif os(macOS)
    return Observable.error(NSError(domain: "Unimplemented", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
#endif
```

can anyone explain why this is not working? or even offer a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by `retry is not called? Is `retryWhen` not called? `retryWhen` is only called when an error occurs. Are you sure that the error occured?